# Converting BYTEA- UTF8 to text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with a column called temperature. This column is in BYTEA and the databse is encoded as UTF8. I am trying to represent this data in text format, whatever the data is saved, but I cannot. Is there anyone can help me ? 
I tried to encoded into a string and then that string convert it to a text, but is not working as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.character_sets;
```

[image]

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='tab_measuredata' AND table_schema = 'public';
```

[image]

So the type is BYTEA and I cannot see the data which is recorded or even better, how is recorded. I am trying to convert it into a readable way. I tried to change to hex and get it from there to text without succes.

```
SELECT encode(temperature::bytea, 'hex')
FROM tab_measuredata
LIMIT 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe the exact format of the binary data?

Comment: Sure. My data base records depth, temperatures besides other parameters. When I explore the data, I get that the DataBase is encoded as UTF8. Within this tables, there is one column which I am interested in and is the type BYTEA. However, as the query is not showing me what is written or even better, how is written the data recorded. I want to show it in a readable format. convert it already to HEX trying to get the data but I cannot. I am wondering How can I solve this.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my question was what is the format of the `bytea` column? What do the individual bytes in it mean?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing a "temperature" in a `bytea` column? That should be stored in an `integer` or `float` or `numeric`.

Comment: Hola, It was created by another company. Not me, I think that is the problem because I am assuming the data stored there contains not just integer characters. Because the device measures temperature every 4 minutes for lines up to 2 km every meter. I am looking for this answer as well.